# Show and hide password variable in GeneXus SD

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

Is it possible to create a button that show/hide the user password during the login in GeneXus SD?

For example, this "eye" button beside the “password” field in this app:

[image: app example]

How can I develop this feature? I'm using Gx15 U1.

Comment: JFYI, this feature will be available "soon" in GX v15 upgrades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way of showing the text of a password control.

You could add two controls, one of them being the `&password` and another one a regular `&text` variable (with the same text the password has).

And when taping on that "eye"  button you could show the regular `&text` and hide the `&password`.